# 401 error page not working with ht access auth

Tags: .htaccess

```
Additionally, a 401 Unauthorized error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I've been getting this error and the custom 401 page isn't getting triggered.

I've searched the whole of stackoverflow for answers and a few which I found didn't worked. Like allowing URL etc.

Can anyone tell where I am doing it wrong;.

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404/

ErrorDocument 401 /var/www/www-root/data/www/jackjonanune.com/duck.html

AuthUserFile /var/www/www-root/data/www/jackjonanune.com/.htpasswd
AuthName "Must Log In"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from 103.221.211.201
satisfy any
```

I also tried adding

```
<Location /var/www/www-root/data/www/jackjonanune.com>
  Allow from all
  Satisfy Any
</Location>
```

But it brings in 500 internal server error

Comment: My guess is that the relative path of the 404 folder is wrong, since this is accessing the folder /404/ on your filesystem which seems to be wrong, not some path from your web directory.

Comment: I mean I want to fix the 401 not the 404

Comment: The error on the very top means, that a 401 error was thrown when accessing one ErrorDocument. So you either want to check if it's the 404 folder which it is trying to access, or if the user for apache doesn't have the permission to access the duck.html (401)